# Возврат массива строк из функции C++

Tags: c++, функции, динамические-массивы

У меня есть функция, обрабатывающая массив строк s[n] и я хочу вернуть результат обработки (из функции rebuild()), чтобы передать его другой функции (show()). Но сталкиваюсь с ошибкой:

```
warning: address of local variable 's' returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]
```

По всякому пытался извернуться, но ничего не вышло.

```
//Funcs.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "regex"

using namespace std;

int input(){
    int n;
    cout<<"n=";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<endl;
    cin.ignore(1, '\n');
    return n;
}
string* rebuild(int n){
    string s[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int c = 0;
        string t, word;
        cout << "S[" << i << "]= ";
        getline(cin, t);
        cout<<endl;
        t = regex_replace(t, regex("^ +"), "");
        t = regex_replace(t, regex(" +$"), "");
        for (int m = 0; t[m] != ' '; m++){
            c++;
        }
        word = " " + t.substr(0, c);
        t = t.substr(t.find_first_of(" \t")+1);
        s[i] = t + word;
    }
    return s;
}

void show(int n, string* s){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout<<s[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

```
//main.cpp
#include <string>
#include "Funcs.cpp"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n = input();
    string* s = rebuild(n);
    show(n, s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Если в строке не найдется " \t", то  вы будете еще раз обращаться с помощью найти ошибку в программе?... И как вы будете использовать  ее, передав большие числа? Вводить в ручную  сотни строк?.. К тому же  перемешать С++ и Си стили  в одной функции и усложнять  реализацию, есть плохая привычка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашей функции `string s[n];` - локальный массив, который перестанет существовать после выхода из функции `rebuild`. Поэтому указатель, который вы возвращаете из функции, становится невалидным. Варианты:

1. Передать в функцию rebuild указатель на валидный массив:

```
void rebuild(int n, string *s){
    s[...] = ...;
}
int main() {
    int n = input();
    string* s = new string[n];
    rebuild(n, s);
    show(n, s);
    delete s;
    return 0;
}
```

2. Динамически выделять память внутри функции rebuild, при этом помнить о том, что необходимо освободить её где-то в вызывающей функции:

```
string *rebuild(int n){
    s = new string[n];
    s[...] = ...;
    return s;
}
int main() {
    int n = input();
    string* s = rebuild(n);
    show(n, s);
    delete s;
    return 0;
}
```

3. Использовать контейнеры:

```
#include <vector>

vector<string> rebuild(int n){
    vector<string> s;
    s.push_back("string1");
    return s;
}

int main() {
    int n = input();
    vector<string> s = rebuild(n);
    show(n, s); //переделайте эту функцию тоже, чтобы она обрабатывала вектор
    return 0;
}
```